# Remove largest number from a list and sum the remaining numbers

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of numbers (27763 rows, csv file) and want to do following things:

1. Finding maximum number in the list and put it in another list named maximumvalue
2. Adding the remaining number together, calculate their sum and put it in another list named totalvalue
3. Removing the maximum number and do the above steps again and again

I have written the following scripts but it only shows me 13882 numbers in maximumvalue list that is totally different from 27763:

```
sample=open("file.csv")   
sampledata=csv.reader(sample)  
B=[]  
maximumvalues=[]  
totalvalues=[]  
for row in sampledata: 
   values=row[2]  
   B.append(float(values))
for value in B:  
   maximumvalues.append(max(B))  
   totalvalues.append(sum(B))  
   B.remove(max(B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, it is hard to tell - but did it occur to you that you may have more than 1 maximum value in the list? Sorting the initial values may help:

```
maximuvalues = sorted(B, reverse=True)
totalvalues = [sum(B)]
for val in itertools.islice(maximumvalues, 1, None):
    totalvalues.append(totalvalues[-1] - val)
```

Comment: this is true but sorting is inefficient if you only need to subtract the max number * it's number of occurences